# How add corner radius to dashed border around an UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have a rounded `UIView` and I have added a dashed line stroke to it.

```
,,,
    var view = CAShapeLayer()
    view.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    view.frame = addphotoView.bounds
    view.fillColor = nil
    view.path = UIBezierPath(rect: addphotoView.bounds).cgPath
    view.cornerRadius = 16
    view.masksToBounds = true

    addphotoView.layer.addSublayer(yourViewBorder)
```

But `view.cornerRadius` is not working as expected:
[image: Demo]

> Corner is wiped out.

Comment: I have updated your code and image due to visual issues (that I had with the preview image)

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I will remember that to be more careful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Quick Answer

You should round the `Layer`s `path`.

like this:

```
borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: addphotoView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)).cgPath
```

---

---

## Better Answer Using An Extension

You can move all this logic into an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    @discardableResult
    func addLineDashedStroke(pattern: [NSNumber]?, radius: CGFloat, color: CGColor) -> CALayer {
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        borderLayer.strokeColor = color
        borderLayer.lineDashPattern = pattern
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        borderLayer.fillColor = nil
        borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath

        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        return borderLayer
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
addphotoView.addLineDashedStroke(pattern: [2, 2], radius: 16, color: UIColor.gray.cgColor)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: I have tried your answer and in my case, I have two views in the horizontal stack so dotted line goes out from the view horizontally. Any idea?

Comment: You should update the layer somewhere like `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Thanks for the extension! Can we somehow avoid the dashed lines touching at the start and end of the path? Its visible in your example view screenshot as well next to the top left corner.